# Additional parent entities being created when adding child entities to parent using CoreData and SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am using Xcode 13.2 and building for iOS 15. I have a parent entity "ARProject" and a child entity "ARScene" There is a project list view, an add project view, a project scene list view, and an add scene view. Adding and deleting projects is working fine. I can also pass a project to the project list view and display information about the project and then pass the project to the add scene view and create a scene that is added  to the project. When I return to the project scene list view the scene list has been updated. However when I return to the project list view an additional project has been added with no attributes set. Deleting this ghost project removes the scene from the original project. Can someone point out what is causing this? I have included the code. Thank you for help.
This is the ARProject List View:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var showAddProjectView = false
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: ARProject.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ARProject.arProjectTimestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)

    var  projects: FetchedResults<ARProject>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(projects, id: \.self) { project in
                    HStack {

                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            NavigationLink(destination:
                                ProjectSceneView(project: project)){
                                Text("\(project.wrappedProjectName )")
                                .font(.headline)
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(height: 50)
                   }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    for index in indexSet {
                        viewContext.delete(projects[index])
                    }
                    do {
                        try viewContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("ARProjects")
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                showAddProjectView = true
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                }))
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddProjectView) {
                AddProjectView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add project view

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddProjectView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    let arProjectTypes = [ "Displsy", "Tour"]
    let sceneTypes = ["Connected", "Separate"]
 
    @State var arProjectName = ""
    @State var selectedProjectIndex = 0
    @State var selectedSceneIndex = 0

 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Project Details")) {
                    TextField("Project Name", text: $arProjectName)
                 
                    Picker(selection: $selectedProjectIndex, label: Text("Project Type")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< arProjectTypes.count) {
                             Text(self.arProjectTypes[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                
                    Picker(selection: $selectedSceneIndex, label: Text("Scene Type")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< sceneTypes.count) {
                            Text(self.sceneTypes[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
                }         
            }
             
             Button(action: {
                 guard self.arProjectName != "" else {return}
                 let newARProject = ARProject(context: viewContext)
                 newARProject.arProjectId = UUID()
                 newARProject.arProjectIndex = 0
                 newARProject.arProjectName = self.arProjectName
                 newARProject.arProjectType = self.arProjectTypes[self.selectedProjectIndex]
                 newARProject.arProjectTimestamp = Date()
                 newARProject.arSceneType = self.sceneTypes[self.selectedSceneIndex]
                 
                 do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                        print("ARProject saved.")
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } catch {
                         print(error.localizedDescription)
                        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    }
             }) {
                 Text("Add Project")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("New Project")
        }
    }
}
```

Project Scene List View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProjectSceneView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var showAddSceneView = false
    @ObservedObject var project: ARProject
   
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(project.arSceneType ?? "") Scenes:")
        .bold()
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        
        HStack {
            List {
                ForEach(project.arSceneArray, id: \.self) { arScene in
             
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("\(arScene.wrappedSceneName )")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("\(project.arProjectName ?? "") \(project.arProjectType ?? "")") )
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            showAddSceneView = true
            }, label: {
                Text("Add Scene")
            }))
       .sheet(isPresented: $showAddSceneView) {
            AddSceneView(project: project)
       }
       .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

Add Scene View

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddSceneView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let project: ARProject
    
    @State var arSceneName = ""
    @State var arSceneDescription = ""
    @State var arSceneOrderAsText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Scene Details")) {
                TextField("Scene Name", text: $arSceneName)
                TextField("Scene Description", text: $arSceneDescription)
                TextField("Scene Order", text: $arSceneOrderAsText)
            }
                
            Button(action: {
                guard self.arSceneName != "" else {return}
                guard self.arSceneDescription != "" else {return}
                guard self.arSceneOrderAsText != "" else {return}
                let newARScene = ARScene(context: viewContext)
                newARScene.arSceneId = UUID()
                newARScene.arSceneOrder = Int16(self.arSceneOrderAsText)!
                newARScene.arSceneName = self.arSceneName
                project.addToArScene(newARScene)
                project.objectWillChange.send() 
                  
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()              
                        print("Scene saved.")
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    }
            }) {
                Text("Add Scene")
               }
           }
           .navigationTitle("New Scene")
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the same logic to see if simplifying it shows the error. One thing I am curious about is why you are sending an `objectWillChange` on `project` in AddSceneView. Also, you can put all of your guard conditions in one guard statement.

Comment: Why is project an ObservedObject in ProjectSceneView, why not a normal property?

Comment: I had 2 issues, the first was an extra project being created when I added a scene, the second was the project scene list view not updating when I added a scene. I solved the second by making project an ObservedObject in ProjectSceneView and sending an objectWillChange on project in AddSceneView based on an answer Apple Developer Forums. [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679567)

Comment: Try making `let project: ARProject` an `@ObservedObject var project: ARProject`

Comment: ARProject is an @ObservedObject in ProjectSceneView

Comment: I decided to look at the core date end of the project as the possible source of issue and created a new project. I set up the CoreData identical to the original project and copied the code over. The issue did not exist in the new project.